# While trying to make a small program in Python, I am getting an: AttributeError: module 'backend' has no attribute 'insert'

Tags: python, tkinter, sqlite

I am trying to write a small program to use at work. It looks like this:

[image]

As you can see there are two dropdown menu's. When clicking on one of the buttons on the menu, filling in the other two Entry's (Korte beschrijving, datum) and clicking on Voeg incident toe (Add new incident) it should be saved as an entry in the database. I guess there are a few things not working and I'm getting two errors:

First I got the: "Option menu has no attribute get" error. Then I made two functions:

```
def drop_down_soort():
soort.get()
window.quit()

def drop_down_user():
user.get()
window.quit()
```

Now I am getting a new error:

This is the entire code: frontend and backend + error.

```
from tkinter import *
import backend

def alle_incidenten():
   tekst_vak.delete(0,END)
   for row in backend.alle():
   tekst_vak.insert(END,row)

def drop_down_soort():
   soort.get()
   window.quit()

def drop_down_user():
   user.get()
   window.quit()

def voeg_toe():
   backend.voeg_toe(drop_down_soort.get(),drop_down_user.get(),
   beschrijving_tekst.get(),datum_tekst.get())
   tekst_vak.delete(0,END)
   tekst_vak.insert(END,(drop_down_soort.get(),drop_down_user.get(),
   beschrijving_tekst.get(),datum_tekst.get()))

window=Tk()
window.wm_title("T I T A A N  Incidenten Register")

soort = StringVar(window)
soort.set("Soort")

menu = OptionMenu(window, soort, "Incident", "RFC", "Opdracht")
menu.grid(row=0,column=0)

user = StringVar(window)
user.set("User")

user_menu = OptionMenu(window, user, "Jesse", "Jan", "Sirano", "Shannon", 
"Niek", "Thomas", "Patrick")
user_menu.grid(row=1,column=0)

l3=Label(window,text="Korte beschrijving")
l3.grid(row=0,column=2)

l4=Label(window,text="Datum")
l4.grid(row=1,column=2)


beschrijving_tekst=StringVar()
l3=Entry(window,textvariable=beschrijving_tekst)
l3.grid(row=0,column=3)

datum_tekst=StringVar()
l4=Entry(window,textvariable=datum_tekst)
l4.grid(row=1,column=3)

tekst_vak=Listbox(window,height=10,width=35)
tekst_vak.grid(row=2,column=0,rowspan=6,columnspan=2)

scrollbar1=Scrollbar(window)
scrollbar1.grid(row=2,column=2,rowspan=10)

tekst_vak.configure(yscrollcommand=scrollbar1.set)
scrollbar1.configure(command=tekst_vak.yview)

b1=Button(window,text="Alle incidenten", width=14, bg='Gray', 
command=alle_incidenten)
b1.grid(row=2,column=3)

b2=Button(window,text="Voeg incident toe", width=14, bg='Gray', 
command=voeg_toe)
b2.grid(row=3,column=3)

b3=Button(window,text="Pas incident aan", width=14, bg='Gray')
b3.grid(row=4,column=3)

b4=Button(window,text="Verwijder incident", width=14, bg='Red')
b4.grid(row=5,column=3)

b5=Button(window,text="Sluit programma", width=14, bg='Orange')
b5.grid(row=6,column=3)


window.mainloop()
```

Backend:

```
import sqlite3

def verbind_met_database():
    verbinding=sqlite3.connect("titaan_incidenten.db")
    cur=verbinding.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS titaan_incidenten
    (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, soort TEXT, user TEXT, beschrijving TEXT, 
    datum TEXT)")
    verbinding.commit
    verbinding.close()

def alle():
    verbinding=sqlite3.connect("titaan_incidenten.db")
    cur=verbinding.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT * FROM titaan_incidenten")
    rijen=cur.fetchall()
    verbinding.close()
    return rijen

def voeg_toe(soort,user,beschrijving,datum):
    verbinding=sqlite3.connect("titaan_incidenten.db")
    cur=verbinding.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO titaan_incidenten VALUES (NULL,?,?,?,?)", 
    (soort,user,beschrijving,datum))
    verbinding.commit()
    verbinding.close()

def pas_aan(id,soort,user,beschrijving,datum):
    verbinding=sqlite3.connect("titaan_incidenten.db")
    cur=verbinding.cursor()
    cur.execute("UPDATE titaan_incidenten SET 
    soort=?,user=?,beschrijving=?,datum=? WHERE id=?", 
    (id,soort,user,beschrijving,datum))
    verbinding.commit
    verbinding.close()

def verwijder():
    verbinding=sqlite3.connect("titaan_incidenten.db")
    cur=verbinding.cursor()
    cur.execute("DELETE FROM titaan_incidenten WHERE id=?",(id,))
```

ERROR:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\crisc\Anaconda3\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __ 
call__
return self.func(*args)
File "frontend.py", line 18, in voeg_toe

backend.voeg_toe(drop_down_soort.get(),
drop_down_user.get(),beschrijving_tekst.get(),datum_tekst.get())
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'get'
```

For me, working with the dropdown menu's is something I never done before. So maybe the functions I created are not necessary. If somebody could give me some pointers on how to get that menu working, that would be great!

I edited it with the correct error and code. Sorry for the earlier confusion.

Thanks,

Cris

Comment: This doesn't have anything to do with menus. `backend` is the module you defined, and you didn't give it an `insert` function. What are you expecting that to do?

Comment: You're calling a function-`insert`- which does not exist!!

Comment: Sorry guys, I edited the code. Now it has the correct code and error.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you've provided, you're passing the wrong parameters to `backend.voeg_toe()` function. Rather than using `drop_down_soort.get()`, `drop_down_user.get()`, you should pass just these functions without `.get()` which does not make sense to your function, and return values inside the function.

Function bodies can contain one or more return statement. They can be situated anywhere in the function body. A return statement ends the execution of the function call and "returns" the result, i.e. the value of the expression following the return keyword, to the caller. If the return statement is without an expression, the special value None is returned. If there is no return statement in the function code, the function ends, when the control flow reaches the end of the function body and the value "None" will be returned.

for example:

```
def drop_down_soort():
   test = soort.get() #not sure even if soort.get() is getting any value, but I suppose yes!!!!
   window.quit()
   return test

def drop_down_user():
   test = user.get() #not sure even if user.get() is getting any value, but I suppose yes!!!!
   window.quit()
   return test
```

so then whenever you call `backend.voeg_toe(drop_down_soort(),drop_down_user(),....)` it will get the returning values of those two functions and will pass it as parameters.

Comment: Still getting the same error when deleting .get(). I want to select something from the dropdown menu's, type something in the Entry boxes and then click on the Voeg Incident Toe button. And that's when I get the same error. So it runs the program, and as soon as I select something from the dropdown buttons and enter some text in the Entry boxes. Finally I click on the widget button and then it returns the error.

Comment: Your code needs to be rewritten a bit. Try to remove the other get() from the function parameters.

Comment: Did you mean:   def voeg_toe():
    backend.voeg_toe(drop_down_soort(),drop_down_user(),beschrijving_tekst(),datum_tekst())
    tekst_vak.delete(0,END)
    tekst_vak.insert(END,(drop_down_soort(),drop_down_user(),beschrijving_tekst(),datum_tekst()))      because now I am gettint a different error: StringVar object is not callable.

Comment: It's pointing that `beschrijving_tekst()` and `datum_tekst()` are not functions so you can't put `()` in front of them to pass as parameters. Those aforementioned variables are already `=StringVar()`, so remove `()` from `beschrijving_tekst()` and `datum_tekst()`, however you still need to work on your code.